# WPF Проблема с многократной цикличной отрисовкой Image через Thread and Dispatcher.Invoke

Tags: wpf, многопоточность, изображения

Я пытаюсь отрисовать обновляющийся график на Image WPF в цикле. Получил - отрисовал. Можно с небольшими паузами между итерациями.
При этом нужно сохранить отзывчивость контролов.
Попробовал использовать Dispatcher Invoke  - в двух вариантах, с циклом внутри Invoke и снаружи. Получается одинаково - окно виснет пока всё не отрисуется.

view это объект, кот рисует Bitmap и передает его для Image.
iView это Image control в MainWindow.

```
private void Draw()
{
    // setting size of image
    view.DataHeight = 500;
    view.DataWidth = TDRConnection.MAX_DATAPOINTS;
    view.Height = (int)gView.ActualHeight;
    view.Width = (int)gView.ActualWidth;

    //drawing     
    iView.Source = view.DrawPixels(connection.GetMeasurementData(),
        TDRConnection.MAX_SUPPORTED_CHANNELS,
        portColors);
}

private void LiveDrawingAS()
{
    Dispatcher.Invoke(() => {
        int safety = 0;
        for (; safety < 300 && doLiveDrawing; safety++) {
            Draw();
            //Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
        MessageBox.Show($"Done {safety} drawings");
    });
}
private void LiveDrawingNAS()
{
    int safety = 0;
    for (; safety < 300 && doLiveDrawing; safety++) {
        Dispatcher.Invoke(() => {
            Draw();
            //Thread.Sleep(100);                    
        });
    }
    MessageBox.Show($"Done {safety} drawings");
}

private void bLive_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    doLiveDrawing = true;
    new Thread(new ThreadStart(LiveDrawingAS)).Start();
}

private void bStop_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    doLiveDrawing = false;
}
```

Пробовал вариант с рисованием bitmap вовне Invoke, и тогда MainWindow отзывчиво, но Image control пустой, так что все равно не то:

```
    private void LiveDrawingNAS()
    {
        WriteableBitmap wbm;

        int safety = 0;
        for (; safety < 30 && doLiveDrawing; safety++) {
            wbm = DrawBitmap();
            Dispatcher.Invoke(() => {
                iView.Source = wbm;
            });
        }
        MessageBox.Show($"Done {safety} drawings");
    }
```

Прошу помочь советом

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я нашел решение. Нужен Freeze для bitmap. Тогда Имадж обновляется без задержек, а окно при этом отзывчиво:

```
    private void LiveDrawingOutUI()
    {
        WriteableBitmap wbm;

        int safety = 0;
        for (; safety < 300 && doLiveDrawing; safety++) {
            wbm = DrawBitmap();

            wbm.Freeze();
            Dispatcher.Invoke(() => {
                iView.Source = wbm;
            });
        }
        MessageBox.Show($"Done {safety} drawings");
    }
```

Cheers!

Comment: В таком случае, полагаю, Вы можете пометить этот ответ как правильный, отметив его галочкой, либо дождаться других ответов — вдруг они будут более красивыми и практичными :)

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо за совет! Т.к. я перепробовал разные варианты, то пока помечу этот как правильный.... Через 2 дня, потому что раньше нельзя :)